# Statically derived type in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, typedef, traits

I'm looking for a C# alternative to C++ typedefs or traits classes in a specific case. I know that there are no direct equivalents, but perhaps there are some alternative solutions for this specific problem?

Here is what I'm trying to do. I'm writing a framework where there are three related types. A view, a backing storage and a factory. There will be multiple implementations of all three interfaces. There is a 1-1 relation between the view and the factory and there is a 1-N relation between the view and the storage. A concrete impl. of the framework looks something like this:

```
Storage : IStorage<int> ...

View : IView<Storage> ... // And IView<T> : IViewNonGeneric further up..

Factory : IFactory<Storage> {
  // This needs to take a concrete storage type as arg
  IViewNonGeneric CreateView(Storage s) ... 

  Storage CreateStorage() ...  
}
```

The View class is the most important class for the users of the framework; the others are kind of implementation details. Because of this it would seem more natural to define the Factory in terms of the View class (and not in terms of the Storage). In C++ this would be straight forward, just add a typedef to the view and use it in the factory, like so:

```
class IView<typename T> { typedef T TStorage; ...

class IFactory<typename T> { 
  IViewNonGeneric CreateView(typename T::TStorage s) ...
```

In C# we obviously don't have typedefs or traits classes. Is there any other way to accomplish the desired effect? That is, can one use View as the generic parameter to the Factory and derive the concrete Source type from the View?

Comment: Isn't enough to use `where` in generics declaration to constrain the type have to be implemented?

Answer (score 3):

Generics in C# are definitely not as powerful as templates in C++.  However, C# does have something very powerful that C++ doesn't have: Reflection.

It should be very easy to define a method (either static or instance) on the view class that would return the concrete type of storage class.  Then you can use Type.GetConstructor to dynamically find a constructor of the storage class and invoke it using ConstructorInfo.Invoke method.

Additionally, you can explore the use of custom attributes that you could assign to your view class. How about something like this:

```
[StorageType( typeof( MyStorage1 ) ]
class MyView1 { ... }
```

Then use reflection on typeof( MyView1 ) to see if it has StorageTypeAttribute associated with it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This might be the closest I get, but unfortunatelly it won't work since it would require changing the Factory functions signatures.

Comment: Not sure I follow you why you'd have to change Factory function signatures.  You could make factory a generic class. Or... you could combine reflection with attributes

Comment: In the IFactory<T> interface I have: T CreateStorage() (where T : IStorage). What would the sig. of this function be if the IFactory interface generic parameter was changed to represent a view instead of the storage?

Comment: So your concrete storage class specifies what kind of view to load, correct? If that's the case, can you have custom attribute on the storage class (just like the example with the MyView1 I listed above) and have factory read that? The only thing is that your IFactory<>.CreateView() method would have to take some base type as parameter instead of T::TStorage and instead of strong type, it would have to return a base as well, which you already do in your original example.  If we are still not talking about the same thing, you might want to expand your original example a little

Comment: I understand the solution that you are suggesting. Thank you for taking the time to share it. Your solution takes care of the "CreateView(Storage)" function. But it still won't solve the "Storage CreateStorage()" where the Storage is ideally a concrete type and not an interface. The reason it would be bad to return an interface is that it would force a user to cast on assignment: ie. SomeConcreteStore s = (SomeConcreteStore)CreateStorage()

Comment: Yep, unfortunately you are stuck with that cast and I know exactly how you feel. We did get spoiled by C++ templates; if not abused too much, they can do truly wonderful things for us.  Btw, I was doing some completely unrelated browsing earlier today and came across MS T4 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx). Instead of generics, you could probably write a code generator to auto-create all the types you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think is what you want:

```
public interface IStorage<T>
{
}

public class IntStorage : IStorage<int>
{
}

public interface IFactory<S, T> where S : IStorage<T>
{
    IView<S, T> CreateView(S storage);
}

public interface IViewNonGeneric
{
}
public interface IView<S, T> : IViewNonGeneric where S : IStorage<T>
{
}

public class IntView : IView<IntStorage, int>
{
}

public class IntFactory : IFactory<IntStorage, int>
{
    public IntView CreateView(IntStorage storage)
    {
        // create the view
    }
    // private interface implementation
    IView<IntStorage, int> IFactory<IntStorage, int>.CreateView(IntStorage storage)
    {
        return CreateView(storage);
    }
}

...
```